# htaccess wildcard subdomain regardless of set-up subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

Bind DNS Settings:

```
*.se7en.net.pl   A  Default 12.34.56.789
```

Apache Virtual Host:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/wild
ServerAlias *.se7en.net.pl
<Directory "/var/www/wild">
    allow from all
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This works for redirecting to `/var/www/wild` directory whenever i type ANY subdomain.
However, when I create .htaccess file in `/var/www/wild` and it gots:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^se7en\.net\.pl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://se7en.net.pl/hta.php?id=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Got an error 403 Forbidden Access...

I want to achieve that effect:
If I go to `tits.se7en.net.pl` I want this page to be called: `http://se7en.net.pl/hta.php?id=tits`, but I have no idea how to do it ;(

It started to work once i used this code:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.se7en\.net\.pl$
RewriteRule .* http://test.se7en.net.pl/hta.php?id=%1 [L]`

However, whenever i go into `tits.se7en.net.pl` the address bar changes to `http://test.se7en.net.pl/hta.php?id=tits`, which was something i wanted to hide.
Is this possible to hide?

Comment: Here is a great resource for `.htaccess` rules https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Comment: Yeah it really is nice resource, but maybe I'm stupid, however I don't see anything that fits into my current needs.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do that

Answer (score 0):

If the domain starts with anything other then `domain.com` redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/index.php?page=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: That solution i found on related ones but its not working. Whenever i do it, obviously after i change domain to mine, i got 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: `%1` is where the subdomain be re-written

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://se7en.net.pl/hta.php?id=%1 [L,R=301,NC]` But still not working... If i meant to change $ to %. I actually dont need any redirects like `tits.se7en.net.pl/somefile.php`, just plain subdomain with domain. P.s. i edited the problem info, mby it will show better what im stuck with.